# Running an async function with React Native and Firestore returns goofy results

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm trying to learn react native along with firebase firestore and I'm racking my brain trying to figure this situation out.  Below is my code.  I'm trying to pull user information stored in firebase.  The console.log in the function returns the array with all of the values such as `Document data: {"admin": true, "email": "bob@bob.com", "first": "Bob", "last": "BobLastName", "phone": "555-555-5555"}`, however if I try to console.log the return outside of the function or try to assign it to a variable I'm getting.   `LOG  {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null}`.  Any help would be much appreciated before I chuck my laptop out of the window.

```
import { Pressable, Text } from 'react-native';
import { getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';
import { doc, getDoc, setDoc, getDocs, collection, query, where, Firestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../components/FirebaseConfig';
import { useEffect, useId, useState } from 'react';
import { async } from '@firebase/util';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

function HomeScreen() {

//Create an async function that will pull user details from firebase and return them as an object
async function getUserDetails() {
    const user = getAuth().currentUser;
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
        return docSnap.data();
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}

//Call the getUserDetails function and store the returned object in a variable
const userDetails =  getUserDetails();
//log userdetails to the console
console.log(userDetails);

//getUserDetails()

        
    
    return <Text>Welcome   HomeScreen</Text>;
}

export default HomeScreen
```

I've tried to use the above code to get the data to work.  It seems like I am not extracting the data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this kind of behavior because you are calling `getUserDetails()` functions directly but it should be called with `await` or used with `.then()` because it is returning a `Promise<DocumentData>` refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentdata)

Basically it will return a promise that will eventually resolve with the data.

To Solve this you can either use

```
const userDetails = await getUserDetails();
console.log(userDetails);
```

OR

```
getUserDetails().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Although using useEffect here is also not a bad option it will look something like this:

```
function HomeScreen() {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserDetails() {
      const user = getAuth().currentUser;
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        const data = docSnap.data();
        console.log("Document data:", data);
        setUserDetails(data);
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }
    getUserDetails();
  }, []);

  if (!userDetails) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }
  return <Text>Welcome {userDetails.first}!</Text>;
}
```

Refer [getDoc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: Thanks again @Rohit Kharche on the answer.  I actually went with the third option because for some reason I couldn't make the first two work.   I made those changes and it works but the console log shows the results repeated for some reason.  Any thoughts what could be causing that?